# Chromium Driver With Selenium C# on Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian OS) Failing With Version Issues

Tags: c#, .net, linux, selenium, raspberry-pi

**What I have**

1. I've a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian OS (Flavor of Linux).
2. It has a "Chromium" browser pre-installed which says is on latest version.

**What I want**

1. I need to do some scraping works on it
2. I prefer to use .NET 6 to do the coding. It works flawlessly on my Windows 11 PC
3. I want to make it work on Raspberry Pi
4. I've installed .NET runtimes and other pre-requisites on the Pi and can run any .NET programs I'm doing on my PC.

**What's The Issue**

1. I checked what version of Chromium browser I've currently at this moment and saw it's

> 92.0.4515.98.

[image]

2. The I installed latest Chromium driver using this Linux command:

> sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver

[image]

3. Everything looks to be good. But now when I'm running my program on Linux, I'm getting the following error. Is it related to version issue? If so how can I download a specific version of Chrome Driver in Linux that matches my Chromium version?

[image]

This is my Chrome initialization code where I get a handle of Chrome and then scrape with it

```
public ChromeDriver StartChromium(bool openBrowser)
{
  var options = new ChromeOptions
  {
    AcceptInsecureCertificates = true,
  };
  if (!openBrowser)
  {
    options.AddArguments("headless");
  }
  var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
  service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
  service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
  options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
  return new ChromeDriver(service, options);
}
```

Comment: [This forum post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=303452) has a procedure which may allow you to install the latest version of Chrome on Raspbian.

Comment: The error message says it all: *"This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 104. Current browser version is 94."* You need to downgrade to ChromeDriver version 94.x or upgrade Chromium to 104.x.

Comment: Hi Greg, I've got it and mentioned in question itself. I would like to know the command to downgrade Greg

Comment: It should be `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver=X` where you replace `X` with a specific version. There is an HTTP endpoint that returns ChromeDriver versions. I don't have time to write up an answer at the moment, but check out the [version selection page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) on Chromium.org.